# AngularJS testing : Jasmine mock callback

Tags: angularjs, testing, callback, jasmine

I have basic angular JS knowledge but I'm very new to Jasmine unit testing.
My issue is the following :

I need to test a service method (method from myService) :

```
myService.method = function(args)
{
    var parameter = "myParam";
    anotherService.anotherMethod(parameter, function(result)
    {
        //Stuff to test using result
        if(result == "blabla")
            testFunction("param");

    });
};
```

How can I mock anotherService.anotherMethod to return a result and test the rest of myService.method ? I need to check that for example that testFunction has been called with "param" (with expect(myFunction)toHaveBeenCalledWith("param")).

Thansk for your help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What I wanted to do was create a fake function for my AJAX call and use one its arguments :

```
spyOn(anotherService, 'anotherMethod').and.CallFake(function(){
  //Get args : fake result of AJAX call and callback
  var fakeResult = arguments[0];
  var callback = arguments[1];
  return callback(fakeResult);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do thies with Jasmine Spies, but I suggest using Sinon, becuase it supports more functionality.

Documentation for this is here:  [Sinon](http://sinonjs.org/)

If you don't have the freedom to use Sinon, here's a Jasmine Spy cheatsheet: 
[Jasmine Spy Cheatsheet](http://tobyho.com/2011/12/15/jasmine-spy-cheatsheet/). As explained in this,

```
var testPerson = new Person();
spyOn(testPerson, "getName");
testPerson.toString();
expect(testPerson.getName).toHaveBeenCalledWith("param");
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have the freedom of adding/removing libraries, I need to do this with jasmine !

Comment: I need to mock anotherService.anotherMethod and its result because it does an AJAX call.

Comment: are you using the http service to do this?

Comment: Yes. Sorry, I think my question wasn't very clear... I posted the answer below.